# why is my python script saying I have an ssl certificate error when all my certificates are up to date

Tags: python, api, ssl, websocket, python-multithreading

I'm trying to connect via websockets to a service called Alpaca, basically you subscribe to there server and they send stock data back through the websocket to your computer. Everything is running perfectly fine except when I try to run the software I get:
ERROR:root:error while consuming ws messages: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)
I check and updated my certificates about 1000 times and that clearly does nothing. I ran the code on another laptop that has python on it and when I ran it on that machine everything went fine. Its really weird and I cannot figure it out for the life of me so any help would be fantastic. the code below is actually what I'm running except I don't have my api keys since those need to be kept a secret.

```
import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi
import threading
conn = tradeapi.stream2.StreamConn('api_key','api_secret_key','https://paperapi.alpaca.markets')
@conn.on(r'^trade_updates$')
async def on_trade_updates(conn, channel, trade):
    print('trade', trade)def ws_start():conn.run(['account_updates', 'trade_updates'])
ws_thread = threading.Thread(target=ws_start, daemon=True)
ws_thread.start()
```

Comment: did you check that the machine where the problem occurs has its date and time correctly set, e.g with NTP service?

Comment: Try `pip install --ugrade certifi` and see if that helps.

Comment: I have already used pip install --upgrade certifi and it didn't help

Comment: @piwai, not quite sure what that means, how would I check that?

Comment: On windows, check the clock, or on Linux juste type "date" in a termi,nal and verify that the machine is set to the current time. If it's set in the past or on the future, it could be out of the SSL certificate validity period, especially if it's short.

Comment: ok I just check it and its all up to date I also check the expiration of the SSL certificate and its still good for like 5 more months. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?